# wrong number of observations - nobs

Tags: r, object, dataframe

I am just written my "complete" function (R programming - Coursera) but something is not working as expected.

```
 complete <- function(directory,id=1:332){

 #create a list of files
 list_files<-list.files(directory,full.names = TRUE)
 #create an empty data frame
 dat <- data.frame()

 for(i in id){
   #read in the file
temp<- read.csv(list_files[i],header=TRUE)
#delete rows that do not have complete cases
temp<-na.omit(temp)

#count all of the rows with complete cases
tNobs<-nrow(temp)

#enumerate the complete cases by index
dat<-rbind(dat,data.frame(i,tNobs))
  }
  return(dat)
}
```

When I ask:

```
cc <- complete("specdata", c(6, 10, 20, 34, 100, 200, 310))
print(cc$nobs)
```

it returns NULL. WHY? it should return:
228 148 124 165 104 460 232

Comment: where did you define `nobs` as column name?  Please check the `colnames(cc)` If you have used `data.frame(col1 = i, nobs  = tNobs)`, then the column name is `nobs`

Comment: akrun. yep you are right. thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `data.frame` was creating by not assigning the column names.  So, it will take the object name as the column name i.e. `tNobs` for the second column.

```
i <- 2
tNobs = 10
data.frame(i, tOobs)
#   i tOobs
#1 2    10
```

So, when we call the `nobs` that doesn't exist in the data.frame, it gives `NULL`

```
dat <- rbind(dat, data.frame(col1 = i, nobs = tNobs))
```